# CSS: Chrome browser doesn't leave a space between menu elements

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, margin, padding

EDIT:

I found a solution myself. The width and height in my a element should be put in the li element instead. So these:

```
    width: 7vw;
    height: 7vw;
```

Into the li:)

---

I have been at it for a while and I just can't figure it out. Internet explorer and Firefox seem to display my menu correctly, but Chrome doesn't.

Here's the html:

```
<div id="navigationmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

And here's the CSS.

I have a lot of stuff there, but I posted it all. Maybe something is interfering??

```
#navigationmenu a {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #a2a2a2;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    line-height: 7vw;
    text-align: center;
    width: 7vw;
    height: 7vw;
    border: 1px #a2a2a2 solid;
    background: #ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 2.1%;
    margin-right: 2.1%;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
    transition-property: box-shadow;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -o-transition-duration:400ms;
    -o-transition-property: box-shadow;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#navigationmenu a:hover{
    background:#ffffff;
    border: 1px #a2a2a2 solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
#navigationmenu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I have already tried putting the **a** element margin and padding to 0 and applying the left and right margins to the **li** elements instead, but this made the li elements go too far from each other in Firefox (in Chrome they were a little better, but not ok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following css to add margin between the `li` elements in you `ul`

Live example here:

http://jsbin.com/piyilafupe/1/

```
#navigationmenu ul li {
    margin-right: 50px; /* ADD YOU DESIRED DISTANCE HERE */
}
```

Notes: if for any reason you need to remove the margin on the most right element you can add this

```
#navigationmenu ul li:last-child  {
        margin-right: none;
}
```

Comment: In Firefox they stay too far from each other and in Chrome they're stacked on one another still...

Comment: How many pixel should the distance among them? You can simply experiment yourself changing the value  margin-right

Comment: I have tested the code on Chrome and Firefox and work fine to me, simply adjust margin-right alternatively post a jsbin with all your css code so we can double check it :-) thanks

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with my Chrome lol. Anyway, I found another solution! -webkit-margin-start and -webkit-margin-end.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the margin to the `<li>` elements instead of the `<a>`

You can get rid of the following code in #navigationmenu a

```
margin-left: 2.1%;
margin-right: 2.1%;
```

Instead do this

```
#navigationmenu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it looks too wide in FF and in Chrome they're still stacked on each other, but not that much.

Comment: I think you were on the right track though. I was messing around a little bit more with my code and found that when I take the height and width of 7vw out from my a element and put it inside the li element instead it will fix some layout problems.